# OpenStack custom Dashboard

Tags: openstack

I am looking for way to create simple multiuser Dashboard for OpenStack as alternative to Horizon. Idea is keep Horizon for administrators and manage users in another aplication with possibility to create (with admin confirmation) custom system.

My idea is create a web aplication (Node.js) which would communicate with OpenStack REST API because we need some extra feature (messaging, LDAP/AC Auth).

I also looked for some projects like alternative to Horizon, but cant find anything .

My question is, what is better idea? Create custom solution or use some already created Dashboard(which one?) and only modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this open source project:

- https://github.com/cyverse/atmosphere
- https://github.com/cyverse/troposphere

So its frontend is based on ReactJS and BackboneJS and the backend is the Django and DRF which consumes the OS python client API.

As for your question, it depends. The horizon project has a very good plugin registration service that let you easily create custom dashboards and you don't have to worry about many other details.

However, create a new dashboard on your own also sounds cool but it needs a lot more effort and time than using the horizon.

HTH